# XCode 6.4 Swift - Implementation of Facebook Login Error

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpANieebE2M) to implement a Facebook login. I did the exact same thing and checked twice, but get an error while compiling that he doesn't get.

In my AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool
    {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
```

and I get this error for the *second* function: **Definition conflicts with previous value, expected declaration.**

I hope somebody understands the error here, thanks.

Comment: in your code you are writing  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool  two times please try to remove one declaration

Comment: @Nik thank you very much, I'm so damn blind.

Comment: its fine man... i know it happens :)